# Can I use a 5V 1A usb adapter to power a 5V 500mA lamp?

Tags: usb, charger, amperage

Can I use a 5V 1A usb adapter to power a 5V 500mA lamp?

The lamp describes 5V 500mA as max. rated power input

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please quickly realise that this is not a free design house, homework-answering service or an on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows that you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which your post doesn't, I'm afraid. Please revise your question showing your work and findings so far, in considerable detail. Or delete the question if Internet searches give you your answer anyway. Again, a warm welcome to the site.

Comment: To answer the question: yes, you can.

Comment: Yes, it will work fine. Voting to close as duplicaate.